# Clustering using a custom distance metric for lat/long pairs

Tags: cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, dbscan

I'm trying to specify a custom clustering function for the scikit-learn DBSCAN implementation:

```
def geodistance(latLngA, latLngB):
    print latLngA, latLngB
    return vincenty(latLngA, latLngB).miles

cluster_labels = DBSCAN(
            eps=500,
            min_samples=max(2, len(found_geopoints)/10),
            metric=geodistance
).fit(np.array(found_geopoints)).labels_
```

However, when I print out the arguments to my distance function they aren't at all what I would expect:

```
[ 0.53084126  0.19584111  0.99640966  0.88013373  0.33753788  0.79983037
  0.71716144  0.85832664  0.63559538  0.23032912]
[ 0.53084126  0.19584111  0.99640966  0.88013373  0.33753788  0.79983037
  0.71716144  0.85832664  0.63559538  0.23032912]
```

This is what my found_geopoints array looks like:

```
[[  4.24680600e+01   1.40868060e+02]
 [ -2.97677600e+01  -6.20477000e+01]
 [  3.97550400e+01   2.90069000e+00]
 [  4.21144200e+01   1.43442500e+01]
 [  8.56111000e+00   1.24771390e+02]
...
```

So why aren't the arguments to the distance function latitude longitude pairs?

Comment: What does `vincenty` do? Why are you looking at `len(found_geopoints)`?

Comment: The minimum samples to form a cluster depends on the number of geopoints available. vincenty is an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae

Comment: Do I conclude that `latLngA` and `latLngB` are identical - and both are 10 elements long? What do you know about DBSCAN? What is the total size of your `found_geopoints`? What are the units you are working in? Degrees?

Comment: latLngA and latLngB are identical. len(found_geopoints) == 83. I'm working in degrees. I first read about DBSCAN a few day's ago.

Comment: ELKI (not python, though, but Java) has built-in support for geodetic distance, as well as full index acceleration (using R*-trees) for it. This will run in `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I have a similar issue with KNN. Did you find a resolution that allowed you to use the custom function?

Comment: other than using a distance matrix, I did not.

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have found a work around where I compute a distance matrix using:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html
then use it as an argument to `DBSCAN(metric='precomputed').fit(distance_matrix)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with scikit-learn: use the haversine metric with the ball-tree algorithm, and pass radian units into the DBSCAN fit method.

This tutorial demonstrates how to **[cluster spatial lat-long data with scikit-learn's DBSCAN](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/)** using the haversine metric to cluster based on accurate geodetic distances between lat-long points:

```
df = pd.read_csv('gps.csv')
coords = df.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])
db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=ms, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))
```

Notice that the coordinates are passed into the `.fit()` method as radian units, and that the epsilon parameter value must also be in radian units as well.

If you want epsilon to be, say 1.5km, then the epsilon parameter value in radian units would = 1.5/6371.